# Difference between Vue.use and constructor import with VueRouter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

What is the difference between these two options when importing VueRouter?

```
import router from './router'
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});
```

vs

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

I understand that Vue.use installs a plugin, is it necessary when passing it into my Vue instance constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is passing a `router` definition object to the Vue instance. Your second example is registering the `VueRouter` plugin.

The `VueRouter` plugin needs to be registered to `Vue` via `Vue.use(VueRouter)` prior to passing the `router` object.

If you are confused why your first example works, even though you haven't registered `VueRouter`, I'd expect that `Vue.use(VueRouter)` is being called in the `router.js` file being imported.